# Excel VBA Replace with Array Groups

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, replace

Right now I am using a horribly inefficient way for a replacement function:

```
Dim Replacement As String
Dim rngRepVal As Object

Set rngRepVal = Sheets("data").Range(Cells(1, 3), Cells(intRowLast, 3))
Replacement = ActiveCell.Value
rngRepVal.Replace What:="123", Replacement:="ABC", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
rngRepVal.Replace What:="234", Replacement:="ABC", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
rngRepVal.Replace What:="456", Replacement:="DEF", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
... [goes on for 50 lines]
Set rngRepVal = Nothing
```

I am wondering if this can be achieved with arrays. Something like:

```
Dim aWhat() As String
Dim aReplacement() As String

aWhat = Split("ABC|DEF|GHI|JKL", "|")
aReplacement = Split(Array("123", 456")|Array("789","1000"), "|") '<-not sure how to organise this
```

Essentially 123 & 456 get replaced by ABC, 789 & 1000 get replaced by DEF etc. in a replace loop> Any insights on how to organise the two arrays? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Replace`(s) are fine - its the cell by cell loop and selection that is inefficient. Try something like this for three replaces over the entire range at once.

```
Sub Recut()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Sheets("data").Range(Sheets("data").Cells(1, 3), Sheets("data").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
With rng1
    .Replace What:="123", Replacement:="ABC", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
    .Replace What:="234", Replacement:="ABC", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
    .Replace What:="456", Replacement:="DEF", LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
aWhat=Split("ABC|ABC|DEF|DEF|GHI|GHI...","|")
aReplacement=Split("123|456|789|.....","|")
For i=1 to UBound(aWhat)
  rngRepVal.Replace what:=aWhat[i], Replacement:=aReplacement[i], ....
Next i
```

Just make sure there's the same number of elements in both arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think found it, by accident:

```
Dim aOld() As Variant
Dim aNew() As Variant
Dim Group As Variant
Dim Word As Variant
Dim y As Long

aNew = Array("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL")
aOld = Array(Array("123", "456"), Array("789", "1000"))

With Range("A:A")
    For Each Group In aOld
        For Each Word In Group
            .Replace What:=Word, Replacement:=aNew(y), LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
        Next
    y = y + 1
    Next
End With
```