# Excel VBA | bulk replace characters in Range

Tags: vba, excel, replace, excel-2010

I want to execute Replace method on Range object. After so much trials, laconic errors from debugger, and reading documentation, I decided to ask for help.

Why do my Replace methods not work? What about those commented ones?

```
Sub Convert_Sheet()
  Dim set_1 As Range
  Set set_1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:AZ300")

  'set_1.Replace(TextBoxSourceJobPrefix.Text, TextBoxTargetJobPrefix.Text, xlWhole, xlByRows, True, )
  'Set set_1 = Replace(set_1.Value, UCase(TextBoxSourceNode.Text), UCase(TextBoxTargetNode.Text))

  set_1.Replace What:=TextBoxSourceJobPrefix.Text, Replacement:=TextBoxTargetJobPrefix.Text, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
  set_1.Replace UCase(TextBoxSourceNode.Text), UCase(TextBoxTargetNode.Text)
  set_1.Replace TextBoxSourceGroup.Text & "G", TextBoxTargetGroup.Text & "G"
  set_1.Replace TextBoxSourceGroup.Text & "Z", TextBoxTargetGroup.Text & "Z"
  set_1.Replace LCase(TextBoxSourceNode.Text), LCase(TextBoxTargetNode.Text)
  set_1.Replace TextBoxSourceJobOwner.Text, TextBoxTargetJobOwner.Text
End Sub
```

Each time I get `Object required` error:

[image]

Even if I opaque with `With`:

```
  With set_1
    .Replace What:=TextBoxSourceJobPrefix.Text, Replacement:=TextBoxTargetJobPrefix.Text, MatchCase:=True        
    .Replace What:=TextBoxSourceJobPrefix.Text, Replacement:=TextBoxTargetJobPrefix.Text, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=True
  End With
```

`Replace` syntax (a method of `Range` object):

[image]

So there IS a function that doesn't need as first parameter the String to be replaced. But why do all my trials fail? Do I have to execute a command with all the parameters? I need only one - `MatchCase`.

Is there a way to replace characters in range in bulk mode? (not using `Replace(text, toReplace, ReplaceWith)` )

I already found those questions helpful, but I still get errors:

[excel vba replace failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815126/excel-vba-replace-failure)

[Excel VBA Replace with Array Groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158997/excel-vba-replace-with-array-groups)

Comment: What are the values of `TextBoxSourceJobPrefix.Text` and `TextBoxTargetJobPrefix.Text` when it crashes?

Comment: What if there is a typo in the names of those text-boxes? Did you set `Option Explicit`?

Comment: @YowE3K is this error due to empty value of Target? What if I want to remove text? Source values are not empty. Example values are IDWK, adwgt_sh.

Comment: set_1.Replace TextBoxSourceJobPrefix.Text, TextBoxTargetJobPrefix.Text, xlWhole, xlByRows, True

Comment: (a) No, the error would not be due to empty value of the replacement string (if that is what you mean by "Target").  (b) Having checked that `TextBoxSourceJobPrefix.Text` and `TextBoxTargetJobPrefix.Text` both return valid strings, check that `Set_1` is still valid - in the Immediate window, type in `?Set_1.Address` and ensure that it shows `$A$3:$AZ$300`.

Comment: Don't use Paranthesis since it required only when you are setting it in to some variable.  In the above case no parenthesis are needed.

Comment: My reply is given for the 1st commented line which is based on the OP's statement "What about those commented ones?"

Comment: Ahh - OK - yes, those parentheses are incorrect.  I was so busy concentrating on the ones that aren't working I wasn't yet looking at the alternatives.

Comment: Thanks @A.S.H for `Option Explicit`. TextBoxSourceJobPrefix is not initialized. Checking on ways to make it visible or initialized.

Comment: If `TextBoxSourceJobPrefix` isn't initialised, why did it show values such as "IDWK" and "adwgt_sh" when you checked the value when it crashes?

Comment: @YowE3K Fields like `TextBoxSourceJobPrefix` were initialized in `UseForm_Initialize()` Sub. @A.S.H I needed to add `UserForm1.` when referencing TextBoxes.

Comment: I assume that last comment meant you didn't look at the values when it crashed - you looked at the values of a completely different `TextBoxSourceJobPrefix` variable at some other time.